# How did the clones land at the battle of Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars, warfare, attack-of-the-clones

In Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones, we see [the Cavalry](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheCavalry) (warning: TVTropes link) arrive in the form of the clone army led by Master Yoda. However, just a few scenes later as Dooku is escaping into space, we only see Trade Federation ships. My question then is: **how did the clones arrive at the battle on the surface?**

Comment: Very well thank you!

Comment: With great panache

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The film's [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) contains some useful info, including several scenes that were written, but not filmed.

I've highlighted the relevant portion:

> **YODA:** *Come on - hurry! Hurry!*
>
> The SURVIVING JEDI dash to the Gunships and scramble in. MACE WINDU hangs on tight as the Gunship, firing all its weapons, rises out of the arena up and over the topmost rim.
>
> EXT. GEONOSIS, TERRAIN OUTSIDE EXECUTION ARENA - DAY
>
> **The massed lines of parked Federation Starships and the DROIDS surrounding the arena, are themselves surrounded by thousands of Republic Starships, disgorging TENS OF THOUSANDS OF CLONE TROOPERS. Beyond, more Republic Starships are landing and spewing out troops.**
>
> INT. GUNSHIP NUMBER ONE - DAY
>
> MACE WINDU stares at the incredible sight.

So the answer is that the clone-troopers who arrived at the arena traveled there in gunships and the majority of the troops who landed, traveled there in **Republic Starships**, which you can clearly see in several of the background scenes

[image]

Comment: +1 for direct movie evidence and not quoting a bloody novelisation!

Comment: I guess then that "Was there a space battle above Geonosis before they landed?" is a separate question.

Comment: @brendanhughes - Yes it is. And one that is very answerable.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel)), as referenced on [this Wikia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Battle_of_Geonosis):

> **huge Republic assault ships** penetrated the upper atmosphere and dropped a fleet of **gunships**, carrying thousands of clone troopers and dozens of AT-TEs as well as Jedi General Yoda, to the surface.

The word "gunships" is a link to the page on [**Low Altitude Assault Transport**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport):

> The Low Altitude Assault Transport (LAAT), also known as the LAAT-series gunship nicknamed "Larties" by some clones, was a gunship series used by the Grand Army of the Republic during the Clone Wars. The series was produced by Rothana Heavy Engineering.

---

**Actual quote from the novelisation (big thanks to @DVK):**

> "Then I'm sorry, old friend," Count Dooku said, in a tone that didn't sound at all sorry. "You will have to be destroyed." He raised his hand and looked to his assembled army, prepared to give the signal. But then Padm, exhausted, dirty, and bloody, raised her head to the sky above and shouted, "Look!" **All eyes turned up to see half a dozen gunships fast descending upon the arena, screaming down in a dusty cloud about the Jedi, clone troopers rushing out their open sides as they touched down**. A hailstorm of laserfire blasted the new arrivals, but the gunships had their shields up, covering the deb arkation of their warriors.
>   [...]
>   Mace could hardly believe the incredible sight unfolding before him, as thousands of Republic ships rushed down on the assembled fleet of the Trade Federation, dropping tens of thousands of clone troopers to the surface of the planet. Behind him, Yoda continued to orchestrate the battle. "More battalions to the left," he instructed his signaler, who relayed it out to the field commanders. "Encircle them, we must, then divide."
>   <sub>-- R.A.Salvatore, *"Attack of the Clones" novelization*</sub>

Comment: Dammit, quoting Star Wars novelisations ... I feel dirty, like some kind of @Richard or something.

Comment: You're quoting Wikia. That's worse :(

Comment: @DVK At least the Wikia article is clearly sourced! I don't have a sad enough life to actually *own* the novelisations ...

Comment: Better?  This one's a freebie

Comment: @DVK I feel bad about this. That's *your* answer now; I shouldn't be getting rep for it!

Comment: Like Cthulu, I shall feed off your misery :)

Comment: @DVK I've made it a hybrid answer now, and included thanks to you :-) The only advantage of my original version was that it said more about what's meant by "gunships", which might be useful.

Comment: You may want to include tidbit on them being delivered by cruisers if you can find the source (NOT there in novelization)

Comment: Or you could, y'know, just post a picture of the Republic Starships actually sitting on the surface of the planet, disgorging troops.

Comment: @Richard - that would involve having to watch creepy whiny Anakin again. Too much pain. "I like watching her..."

Comment: @DVK - I like to think that getting to look at Padmé was the reward for having to look at Anakin