# Where did the Old Republic get the military hardware for the First Battle of Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

So we've determined that there wasn't a [space battle above Geonosis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105214/was-there-a-space-battle-above-geonosis) and that [the clones landed in Republic capital ships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105154/how-did-the-clones-land-at-the-battle-of-geonosis). We know that Yoda went and gathered the clones from Kamino. **But where did they get all of the ships/supplies to transport and equip an entire army?** We know they'd been working on a motion in the Senate, but I doubt they could've gotten funding to build all of those ships let alone had time to do so.

Comment: I don't think canon says anything about it. There's a quote all over the Internet by Lama Su saying that the Kaminoans worked with shipbuilders: "Master Sifo-Dyas requested the most powerful army in the galaxy. We have worked with only the best shipbuilders to fulfill that request." But it doesn't appear in the Episode II script, and I can't find a decent source for it. Wookieepedia's Legends article on the [Acclamator](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acclamator-class_assault_ship) says they were built by Rothana Heavy Engineering. So they were apparently built in advance along with the clones.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith He was quite imaginative. He just didn't think things all the way through ... usually ...

Comment: There are a ton of Legends sources that address in passing that Kuat Drive Yards and Rothana Heavy Engineering were responsible for the development of the ships. Where the funding came from is something more of a mystery, though if one digs into the text of the Republic Commando novels they deal with many accounting...oddities...linking to the Chancellors office. Given how large the Republic is, I don't think it's unfeasible he was able to hide the purchase of the fleet (or the Clones...or do we believe the Jedi paid for all of those alone?).

Comment: Shaddam Corrino paid for it. errr... wrong series

Comment: Uhh the Battle for Geonosis was a couple thousand years after the fall of the Old Republic, re-word the question?

Comment: @Hatandboots that's the problem with the definition of "old" vs "new".  In the context of the post-Empire Republic, the republic that exists during the prequel trilogy is the "old" republic.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hmm, Well I know the republic after the rebels gain control is the new republic, and waayyy back in the day in the greath sith-Jedi war era was the old repulic. Is there a common designation for the time before Sidious gained control?

Comment: This is an issue that involves Disney's new canon system. I can't remember where, but very recently I saw a graphic chart showing that before Disney, the Old and Galactic Republic are one and the same. After Disney took over, the Galactic Republic was founded a thousand years before the Galactic Empire, after the end of the war that destroyed the Sith with Darth Bane as the sole survivor. The Old Republic is a distinct entity that is the immediate predecessor to the Galactic Republic, before that war.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Millions of clones basically do you no good if you can't transport them somewhere.**

This is a quote from the novelization of the Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones:

> "Master Sifo-Dyas requested the most powerful army in the galaxy. We have worked with only the best shipbuilders to fulfill that request."
>   ―Lama Su

The novel is considered canon, and Wikipedia has this [blurb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel)).

> The Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones novelization was written by R. A. Salvatore and published on 23 April 2002 by Del Rey. It is based on the script of the film of the same name. It includes much expansion of scenes and also many scenes which were cut from the movie. Some of them are original to the book.

In the Star Wars novel Tarkin (also canon), there is this exchange between Tarkin and Dooku just before the attack on Geonosis.

> Tarkin tried to decipher the count's inference. "One might almost conclude that you're positing an advantage to going to war. But how would that work? The volunteer security forces of the Confederate worlds against--what, Judicials and ten thousand of your former Jedi brethern?"
>
> Dooku adopted an arrogant expression. "Don't be too surprised, Governor, if the Report has access to secret forces."

Between these two quotes, I think it safe to infer that in addition to building troops, they were also building the hardware necessary to make them a functioning army.

Answer (score 1):

According to Pablo Hidalgo in [Star Wars Insider #62](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_62) the contract with the cloners on Kamino included payment for the development of a fleet of ships and ground vehicles to equip the Clone Army. This was then subcontracted to Rothana Heavy Engineering, a subsidiary of Kuat Drive Yards.

> **Q. Where did all the warships and walkers that the cloners use come from?  Did the Kaminoans build those as well?**
>
> **PH:** The clone army and its hardware came as a package deal, but the Kaminoans didn't build the big guns. An army is pretty useless if you can't move it anywhere,
> so the Kaminoans sub-contracted to the inhabitants of the nearby Rothana system to develop the transports and armor seen in the first battle of the Clone Wars.
>
> Rothana Heavy Engineering, which is a local subsidiary of Kuat Drive Yards, secretly developed the AT-TE and and SPHA-T walkers, the Republic gunships, and the Republic transports. As the clones matured on Kamino, they were trained in the use of this equipment throughout their accelerated lifetimes.