# How did the Jedi rescuers arrive on Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

While Yoda is heading from Kamino to retrieve the clone army, Mace Windu leads a task force of around a hundred Jedi to Geonosis to rescue Obi-Wan, Anakin and Padmé.

We know that Yoda and the clones [arrived in their own Star Destroyers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105154/how-did-the-clones-land-at-the-battle-of-geonosis) but how did the Jedi get there?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did the clones land at the battle of Geonosis?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105154/how-did-the-clones-land-at-the-battle-of-geonosis)

Comment: Almost the exact same question that was previously asked and answered here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105154/how-did-the-clones-land-at-the-battle-of-geonosis

Comment: The Jedi apparently 'borrowed' ships *"...with an open cockpit and the right speed capabilities."*  ;)

Comment: @PaulOmans The question is asking about the Jedi, who arrived *before* Yoda & the clone army.

Comment: @PaulOmans That's unclear. The way the question is worded I can't tell if it means "Rescuers *of* the Jedi" or "Rescuers that *are* Jedi".

Comment: @CreationEdge I'm referring to Mace Windu's team. If you read the question details, I'm clearly not referring to Yoda's team who arrived on Geonosis with the clone army via the Star Destroyer armada. That can only mean I'm referring to Mace Windu's team, who set off for Geonosis while Yoda simultaneously went off to Kamino to pick up the clones and their Star Destroyers.

Comment: Ambiguous pronouns! But thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: There's nothing in either novelisation that covers it, nor in Star Wars in 100 scenes or Ultimate Star Wars.

Comment: I've done an edit. I didn't think the rider was at all necessary, especially if you highlight the linked question.

Comment: Adi Gallia traveled from Coruscant to Geonosis by fighter, according to the Xbox game 'Jedi: Starfighter'; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Starfighter

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe this plot point is ever covered by anything outside of the movies, and I know the movies never address it, but I would assume the republic would provide for the transport of the Jedi in craft similar or identical to the craft used to transport Qui-Gon Jinn and Obi Wan Kenobi in Episode I (A Consular-class Republic Cruiser), obviously with each craft carrying more than two Jedi as the vessels are quite large.

I do not believe they would have arrived all in a fleet of Jedi starships as each traveling individually is very inefficient and since the Jedi have a reputation of being recluses (see Count Dooku's gripes on the Jedi Order) I'm not sure they would have even had that many craft and hyperspace rings available on the short-notice the Counsel received.

Remember at this point the Jedi were basically a specialized Negotiator/Peacekeeper arm of the Republic, and therefore would have had Republic resources at their disposal.